# Unable to install Cordova Ionic using npm

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install cordova ionic using `npm` in `cmd` and with the command `npm install -g cordova ionic` 
**I am getting following errors:**

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idIF5.png)

```
C:\Users\Asus>npm install -g cordova ionic
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program     Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'path' of null
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Asus\npm-debug.log
```

**Note**: I have pre installed android sdk,winant,git,nodejs.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Run `cmd` as an administrator then run the command

Comment: Running cmd as administrator did not help.Still gives the same error!